# How to remove small gap between 2 content?

Tags: html, css

```css
  *, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
input[type="text"] {
   
    background-color: green;
    padding: 7px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
    border: solid 2px #bbb;
    color: white;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color:blue;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 7px;
    color: white;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #ff379f;  
    color: #fafafa;
}
#subscription-email-text-field {
    vertical-align: top;
    display:inline-block; 
    font-size:0.9em; 
    font-weight:400; 
    border:0; 
    width:250px;
    height:32px;
    margin:0;
}
#subscribe-button {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 1px;
    margin:0;
    height:32px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="subscription-email-text-field" name="email" placeholder="box 1">
<input type="submit" id="subscribe-button" value="subscribe">
```

I have a textbox and a button i want to make it inline. But somehow there is a small gap between them.

I'm trying to set up the padding and margin but it doesn't change

How to remove it ? So it will look like this
[image: Example]

Comment: Why did you update your question? Now the answer and question becomes same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between elements. You have a space between the two `input` elements, so you are getting that unwanted space.

Try below snippet

```css
  *, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
input[type="text"] {
   
    background-color: green;
    padding: 7px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
    border: solid 2px #bbb;
    color: white;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color:blue;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 7px;
    color: white;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #ff379f;  
    color: #fafafa;
}
#subscription-email-text-field {
    vertical-align: top;
    display:inline-block; 
    font-size:0.9em; 
    font-weight:400; 
    border:0; 
    width:250px;
    height:32px;
    margin:0;
}
#subscribe-button {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 1px;
    margin:0;
    height:32px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="subscription-email-text-field" name="email" placeholder="box 1"><input type="submit" id="subscribe-button" value="subscribe">
```

Comment: What style did you change?@Harikrishnan N

Comment: @ReynaldHenryleo yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142232/discussion-between-harikrishnan-n-and-reynald-henryleo).